# Dynamic ListView With EditTexts Android

Tags: java, android, listview, android-edittext

I have a ListView in my Android application that uses a CustomAdapterClass. The ListView is populated with rows that contain 2 Edit Texts per row. This is fine, the problem I'm having is the ListView is dynamic, i.e. I have added a button that will append on a new row by calling notifyDataSetChanged(); however this clears the whole list.

How can I keep the text that has been entered into the EditTexts when a new row is appended? Code below:

Activity.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res 
/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">



    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
        android:id="@+id/listViewAddPeople">
    </ListView>


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabAddPerson"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:backgroundTint="#FFFFFF"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Row.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res
/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/personNameEditText"
    android:hint="Enter Persons Full Name"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/personPhoneNoEditText"
    android:layout_below="@+id/personNameEditText"
    android:hint="Enter Phone No. (Optional)"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Java Class:

```
public class AddPeopleNewProcedureActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ListView addPeopleListView;
private CustomAdapterClass customAdapter;
private FloatingActionButton fab;
private int lineCount;
private EditText personsNameET;
private EditText personsPhoneET;
private List<String> personsName;
private List<String> personsPhone;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.addpeoplenew_activity);

    setupActivityReferences();
    inflateListView();
    setupClickListeners();

}

private void setupClickListeners() {
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            lineCount = lineCount +1;
            personsName.clear();
            personsPhone.clear();
            customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });
}

private void inflateListView() {
    customAdapter = new CustomAdapterClass();
    addPeopleListView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
}

private void setupActivityReferences() {
    addPeopleListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewAddPeople);
    fab = findViewById(R.id.fabAddPerson);
    personsNameET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.personNameEditText);
    personsPhoneET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.personPhoneNoEditText);
    lineCount = 1;

}

public class CustomAdapterClass extends BaseAdapter {

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return lineCount;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        view =                
       getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row_addpersonnew,null); 

        final int rowClicked = i;

        return view;
    }
}

}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

> I have added a button that will append on a new row by calling
>   notifyDataSetChanged();

I can't see any append actions when someone clicks that button. I see that you **clear both of your lists**, `personsName` and `personsPhone` and after that you notify your adapter that **those lists are empty**.

Write what really want to be done inside the `onClick()`.